# How to get nicer image instead of youtube still rendered by TYPO3?

Tags: youtube, typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-mask, ext-mask

Using TYPO3 9.5.21 I have a Mask Content Element which creates a list of video-cards. The card image is created when a video url is added in the TYPO3 BE selecting tex-media.
It is processed by TYPO3. To have a nicer more sharp image it would be nice if an image can be selected which than will get the video-link. Instead of the image which is created from the youtube screen. How to achieve that?
I already have a overwrite from the video.html in ext_fluid_content.

adding an image field in the Mask CE is no problem but how to get the video url (which is added through text_media)?)

[image]

[image]

[image]

the Mask code:

```
<!-- sh video_card element -->


<div class="sh_video_card_wrap">
    <div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-3 small-collapse">
<f:if condition="{data.tx_mask_sh_video_show}">

    
    <!-- de losse kaart elemeneten hier -->

<f:for each="{data.tx_mask_sh_video_show}" as="data_item">


<f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_content}">
<div class="column">
<div class="sh_video_card shade">
    

<!-- de video hier in te voegen  -->
<div class="sh_video_card-image-overlay">
<f:for each="{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_content}" as="data_item_item">
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_mask.content">{data_item_item.uid}</f:cObject>
</f:for>
</f:if>
</div>

<!-- video title -->

<div class="sh_video_header_title">
    <h3>
<f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_sub_title}">
{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_sub_title}
</f:if>
</h3>
</div>
<!-- video sub title -->

<div class="sh_video_header_subtitle">
<f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_title}">
{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_title}
</f:if>
</div>

<div class="sh_video_gutter"></div>

<!-- video rich tekst omshrijving  -->
<div class="sh_video_card_content">
    <f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_omschrijving}">
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_RTE">{data_item.tx_mask_sh_video_omschrijving}</f:format.html>
</f:if>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</f:for>
</f:if>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of card element -->
```

Paste bin holding the overwrite for the Video.html file used for this Mask in TYPO3 9.5.22  https://pastebin.com/eUn0BdPQ

Comment: The most important part in your code is `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_mask.content">{data_item_item.uid}</f:cObject>`. In there the video is generated. Would be nice to see the Fluid template of the video itself.

Comment: I can post that as well. I had a file overwrite in TYPO3 9.5 for the fluid_styled_content Style/Video.html  that worked. Now I upgraded to TYPO3 10 and I can not get it to overwrite the file. Still it works but not as nice as I wanted it to. So that is why I decided to test a Mask CE with youtube url and image upload. That is working very well in TYPO3 10.
made a pastebin for the Video.html  https://pastebin.com/eUn0BdPQ    Can not get it to overwrite in TYPO3 10